# A python 3.x KeyError with already 'dict' maybe..?

Tags: python, keyerror

```
def get_data_list(file_object,column_number):
    contents = []
    for string in file_object:
        contents.append(tuple(string.split(',')))
    list = []
    for i in range(len(contents) - 1):
        list.append((contents[i + 1][0], float(contents[i + 1][column_number])))
    list.sort()
    return list

def average_data(list_of_tuples):

    dict = {'01':'January','02':'Februday','03':'March','04':'April','05':'May','06':'June','07':'July','08':'August','09':'September','10':'October','11':'November','12':'December'}
    current_month = 0
    total = 0
    count = 1
    average_data = []
    for k in list_of_tuples:
        for data in k:
            data = str(data)
            month = data[4:6]
            if month == current_month:
                total += k[1]
                if count != 1:
                    count += 1
            else:
                current_month = month
                average = float(total/count)
                average_data.append((float(average),dict[data[4:6]]+data[0:4]))
                total = 0
        average_data = sorted(average_data)
    return average_data
```

These are my code but when I try to run it  returns an error:

> KeyError:'28'or some other keyError with numbers

But I thought I already set all the numbers in dict...
And also, the data[4:6] comes from the date number, such as 20160407, 20141105.